# How do functions work in Elixir?

Tags: function, arguments, elixir

In book "Programming Elixir" Dave Thomas shows an example

```
handle_open = fn
  {:ok, file} -> "Read data: #{IO.read(file, :line)}"
  {_, error} -> "Error: #{:file.format_error(error)}"
end

handle_open.(File.open("code/intro/hello.exs"))
handle_open.(File.open("nonexistent"))
```

I can't understand why second call of function goes into second flow.
Also why we don't pass an argument into func:

```
handle_open = fn(file)
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a multi-clause anonymous function. `handle_open` has 2 clauses, one to match arguments with the pattern `{:ok, file}` and one with `{_, error}`. The first pattern that matches the arguments is executed. The given code is almost <sup>[1]</sup> equivalent to the following:

```
handle_open = fn arg ->
  case arg do
    {:ok, file} -> ...
    {_, error} -> ...
  end
end
```

So if the file exists, `File.open` will return `{:ok, file}` and the first clause will be executed. If it doesn't, `{:error, error}` will be returned which will match the second clause and execute that.

<sup>[1]: "Almost" because the error raised when none of the patterns match will be slightly different for the two cases.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This actually just mimics the pattern-match behaviour of Elixir.

Like you can have pattern match on your Module functions as well.

```
defmodule MyModule do
  def read_file(path) do
    File.open(path) |> handle_file()
  end

  defp handle_file({:ok, file}) do
    // File there..
  end

  defp handle_file({_, error}) do
    // Could not open file.. because of `error`
  end
end
```

Like in the book example, I would try to open the file inside a case clause and delegate the outcome to the appropriate function:

```
defmodule FileReader do

  def read_file(path) do
    case File.open(path) do
      {:ok, file} -> handle_file(file)
      {_, error} -> handle_error(error)
    end
  end

  defp handle_file(file) do
    // File there..
  end

  defp handle_error(error) do
    // 
  end
end
```